# How to use preg_replace to delete content inside an html tag

Tags: php, preg-replace

In the following string, I would like to delete "class2" and "class3" in the class attribute of the span tag

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
$string = '<span class="class1 class2 class3">class1 class2 class3</span>';

$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/class2/';
$patterns[1] = '/class3/';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '';
$replacements[1] = '';

$string = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);

echo htmlspecialchars($string);
```

This returns:`<span class="class1 ">class1 </span>`

This not exactly what I want.

I would like it to return: `<span class="class1">class1 class2 class3</span>`

I don't know what kind of pattern I have to to use to make the replacements only inside the class attribute

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See also [why it's a bad idea to try and do this using regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
preg_replace('/class="class1[^"]*/', 'class="class1', $string);
```

Comment: I see the logic behind your pattern but unfortunately, the class attribute can have a lot of values. I know in advance the set of data I want to delete inside it, but I don't know in advance what other values there will be inside. I would like to target and erase only specific values.